Movie/TV Show with hackers where a computer virus materializes in the real world and can morph items at will
Now this one has been in my memory for forever, but I never figured it out on my own, so I'm giving it to you to try.
I don't know if this was a movie or a TV show, but I recall seeing it on TV sometime in between 1990 and 2000. What I remember:

it was definitely somehow related to computer hackers
I think a program (could have been a virus) materialized into the real world somehow, in the form of a - possibly - blonde woman.
this character was able to morph items into others at will (scene where she picks up a sign from a lawn and morphs it into a handgun, later morphs said handgun into a missile launcher)
to kill her a golden bullet had to be used for some reason (I remember the protagonists buying a lot of golden trinkets from a pawnshop)

If anyone gets this I'll be truly amazed, but also very grateful.

Don't be afraid to use longer titles. Good info in the title is more likely to attract users to your question.

A vulnerability to gold is unusual for high-tech antagonists (exception: the cybermen in Doctor Who). Are you sure it was a program/virus and not something supernatural?

In this movie a computer programm uses human flesh to materialize into the real world somehow.
Virus 1999


I believe it is the TV series Weird Science.

Gary Wallace and Wyatt Donnelly create their dream woman, Lisa, on their computer. Lisa has extraordinary powers and can grant the boys their wishes for short periods of time.


Can you elaborate? Do you remember if any of the scenes mentioned in the question appear there?

I don't remember the guys killing Lisa with a gold bullet.

I dont remember the scenes, but I watched the show and I think it fits the description: Two computer guys create a woman in the computer she becomes real and have the power to concede wishes, i.e. make things appear.

@Catija: I can remember that part neither, but I only watched few episodes of the show.
